# Create a hourly charge schedule based off of user input, plug in or build?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, schedule, timetable

I am building a charge schedule off of the user input for my reflection and I am stuck on whether to try find and adapt a plug in, or build it myself.

The schedule is a solar charge schedule to charge electric cars between the hours of 7am and 16pm. There are 6 cars and 6 solar chargers.

I have built the first table where the user inputs the car registration, the amount of miles left, the amount of miles needed for the next journey and the time they need to leave for that journey.

The schedule must take in to account the above and then generate a charge time table so each car is sufficiently charged for the next journey.

Each car has a maximum range of 250 miles and the cars charge at 44 miles per hour.

Here is the JSFiddle with the whole project: https://jsfiddle.net/Coxy/1r30xgjc/3/

```
// Charge Table
// name =reg & value = carname
var regss = [{
    "name": "NP60UQQ",
    "values": "Little White"
  },
  {
    "name": "NP60UQS",
    "values": "Little Grey"
  },
  {
    "name": "NP60UQT",
    "values": "The Tango"
  },
  {
    "name": "NP60UQU",
    "values": "The Gandalf"
  },
  {
    "name": "NP60UQV",
    "values": "Aqua"
  },
  {
    "name": "NP60UQW",
    "values": "Big Red"
  }
]

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#table_id').DataTable();
});

$('#table_id').DataTable({
  paging: false,
  searching: false,
  select: true
});

$("input[type='text']").change(function() {
//get that values
  var regs = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
//check if have class reg
  if ($(this).hasClass("reg")) {
  //filter json array
    var cars_name = $(regss)
      .filter(function(i, n) {
        return n.name === regs;
      });
      //check if retrn value is > 0
    if (cars_name.length > 0) {
    //add value
      $(this).closest("tr").find(".name").text(cars_name[0].values)
     //hide
     $(this).closest('td').find("span").show().text($(this).val());
      $(this).hide();
     // console.log(cars_name[0].values)

    } else {
    //put mesage not valid
      $(this).closest("tr").find(".name").text("Not a valid Registration")

    }

  }
});

$("input[type='time']").change(function() {
  $(this).closest('td').find("span").show().text($(this).val());

  $(this).hide();
});


$(".reset").click(function() {
  $(".answer").html("");
  $("input").show();
  $('.ltime').val('').prop('disabled', true);
});


$(".confirm").click(function() {
//loop through tr
  $("#table_id tbody tr").each(function() {
    //check reg value is null
    if ($(this).find(".reg").val() == "") {
      $(this).find(".name").text("Please enter valid Registration")
    }
    //get value
    var cmra = $(this).find(".cmr").val()
    var mtnc = $(this).find(".mtnc").val()
    if ((cmra != null && cmra != "") && (mtnc != null && mtnc != "")) {
    //calculate
      var miles = Math.ceil((parseInt(mtnc - cmra)) / 44);
      //console.log(miles)
      $(this).find(".charge").text(miles)
    } else if (cmra == null || cmra == "") {
      $(this).find(".charge").text("Please enter the current miles left")
    } else if (mtnc == null || mtnc == "") {
      $(this).find(".charge").text("Please enter the miles needed for next trip")
    }
  })
});


// Get leave time 

// $(".confirm").click(function() {
//     var car_test = $("#car-1-7").val();
//     var lt_time = $(".time").val();
//     car_test = lt_time;
// });

$( ".leave-input")
$(".confirm").click(function() {
    var value = $( ".leave-input" ).val();
    $( "#car-1-7" ).text( value );
  })

// Generate time table 

$('generate-time-table').click(function() {

})
```

Here is an example I have been given that will hopefully help explain what I mean.

[image: Charge Schedule]

I have looked on Stack and can't seem a similar question, and I have looked for plug ins that may (with some adapting) be able to do this but haven't found any I think will work.

Any ideas or pointers would be really be appreciated, I am quite new to JS and this I feel is a bit beyond my scope and I definitely need advice/help with this.

Thanks for your time.

```
                        <table id="table_id_2" class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th id="car">Car</th>
                                    <th id="7">7 - 8</th>
                                    <th id="8">8 - 9</th>
                                    <th id="9">9 - 10</th>
                                    <th id="10">10 - 11</th>
                                    <th id="11">11- 12</th>
                                    <th id="12">12 -13</th>
                                    <th id="13">13 - 14</th>
                                    <th id="14">14 - 15</th>
                                    <th id="15">15 - 16</th>
                                    <th id="16">16 - 17</th>
                                    <th id="exit_miles">Exit Miles</th>                            
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            
                            <tbody>

                                <tr>
                                    <td id="car-1">Car 1</td>
                                    <td id="car-1-7" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-1-8" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-1-9" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-1-10" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-1-11" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-1-12" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-1-13" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-1-14" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-1-15" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-1-16" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-1-exit-miles">60</td>
                                </tr>  

                                <tr>
                                    <td id="car-2">Car 2</td>
                                    <td id="car-2-7" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-2-8" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-2-9" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-2-10" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-2-11" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-2-12" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-2-13" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-2-14" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-2-15" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-2-16" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-2-exit-miles">60</td>
                                </tr>     
                                    
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="car-3">Car 3</td>
                                    <td id="car-3-7" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-3-8" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-3-9" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-3-10" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-3-13" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-3-12" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-3-13" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-3-14" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-3-15" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-3-16" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-3-exit-miles">60</td>
                                </tr>  

                                <tr>
                                    <td id="car-4" >Car 4</td>
                                    <td id="car-4-7" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-4-8" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-4-9" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-4-10" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-4-11" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-4-12" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-4-13" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-4-14" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-4-15" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-4-16" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-4-exit-miles">60</td>
                                </tr>  

                                <tr>
                                    <td id="car-5">Car 5</td>
                                    <td id="car-5-7" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-5-8" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-5-9" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-5-10" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-5-11" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-5-12" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-5-13" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-5-14" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-5-15" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-5-16" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-5-exit-miles">60</td>
                                </tr>  

                                <tr>
                                    <td id="car-6">Car 6</td>
                                    <td id="car-6-7" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-6-8" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-6-9" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-6-10" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-6-11" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-6-12" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-6-13" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-6-14" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-6-15" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-6-16" class="charging not_charging">Test</td>
                                    <td id="car-6-exit-miles">60</td>
                                </tr>  
                            </tbody>

                        </table>
```

To clarify I am trying to work out the functionality behind this. I have the table created in HTML already, with each cell having it's own id.

I am trying to work out how to: Check which car the leave time relates to, get the leave time, round it to the nearest hour, check how many hours charge it needs before the leave time. Then populate the schedule changing the background colour of the cells that are needed to charge. For example. Car 1 needs to charge for 3 hours and leaves at 12. The schedule would show car 1 row, 8 - 0, 9 - 10, 10 - 11 cells background colour has changed, the exit miles column shows how many miles charge the car has.

I hope this clarifies what I am trying to do.

Edit** Have manged to get the leave time rounded up or down, I am using numbers, not time at the minute. I have the amount of hours needed for charge.

I am now working on how to select the right table cell, and change the back ground colour for that cell, and any cells following it that need changing.

If anyone has any advice, or can at least point me in the right direction of how to do it, or a plug in to use I'd really appreciate the help.

I have made a few advancements on this, and this is the latest fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Coxy/bv5jct7n/13/

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking - are you asking how to calculate/determine the schedule or how to display it?   To display you could either use a table or a bunch of small divs.

Comment: I have created the table, looks just like this one (6 car rows) and the time columns. I'm basically stuck on how to determine/calculate the schedule. Currently I am trying to set each cell to a specific time, i.e car-1 row 7-8 am column  = car 1 , 7am, cell. Does that make sense? Sorry I am not the best at explaining things.

Comment: I have this var c = new Date();
c.setUTCHours(7);
but now (if that has set c to 7am need to set it to the car-1-7 ID.

Comment: I think if i can set each cell to a certain time, I can work out how to change the background for when they are charging, based off of the time the user inputs as time leaving. So if the user needs 3 hours to charge the car, and they are leaving at 11am, the car will charge from 7 - 10am. The cells in the table will change colour for those 3 cells to show it is charging at those times, for that car. Hope that makes sense :/

Comment: An update of the code, obviously isn't working :    function myfunction(){
var lvalue =  $( "#car-1-7" );
var c = new Date();
c.setUTCHours(7);
if (c = lvalue)
$("#car-1-7").toggle("not_charging");

}

$('#generate-time-table').click(function() {
 myfunction();
})

Comment: Scrap the last comment, I can see I am way off there. My first point of call is to round the time leaving to the nearest hour. Then check how many hours charge are needed, then put the car on charge x hours before leave time.

Comment: Updated code : function checkTime(){
  let getRoundedDate = (minutes, d= $("#car-1-7".text())) => {

    let ms = 1000 * 60 * minutes; // convert minutes to ms
    let roundedDate = new Date(Math.round(d.getTime() / ms) * ms);  
    $( "#car-1-7" ).text( roundedDate);
  }
  
  
  // USAGE //
  
  // Round existing date to 60 minutes
  getRoundedDate(60, new Date()); 
  

}

$('#generate-time-table').click(function() {
 checkTime();
})

Comment: Considering stop trying to use time, and just use numbers instead, so the leave time input isn't a time value just a number value, and say to use 24 hours.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue ?

Comment: Partly, I have managed to so some of the code, but it isn't working exactly how it needs to. Here is a JS Fiddle with the latest update. https://jsfiddle.net/Coxy/bv5jct7n/9/

Currently, i have the cells background change but they are on the wrong row. I am working on getting the name in to car name, and trying to get the cells to change background on the correct row.

Comment: I've also done something to stop the input going to upperCase, but I haven't touched the code so no idea why that topped working lol. It's been a challenging week to say the least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user click on `generate` button you first need to loop through first(charge) table to get required data using `$(this).find..` .Now , to calculate leaves get `time` input then use `split` to get the time in array i.e : **a[0]** for *hrs* , **a[1]** for *minutes* and so on  .Then , subtract it with `charge` to get required **leaves** .

Now, to put these info inside another table use `each` loop again . But , here we will loop through `tr > tds` using `tr:eq('+count+')` which will loop one row at a time . Inside this we will need to use for loop to add `background-color` to required `td`. I have added comments in code so you can understand logic behind it .

***Demo code*** :

```js
var regss = [{
    "name": "NP60UQQ",
    "values": "Little White"
  },
  {
    "name": "NP60UQS",
    "values": "Little Grey"
  },
  {
    "name": "NP60UQT",
    "values": "The Tango"
  },
  {
    "name": "NP60UQU",
    "values": "The Gandalf"
  },
  {
    "name": "NP60UQV",
    "values": "Aqua"
  },
  {
    "name": "NP60UQW",
    "values": "Big Red"
  }
]

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#table_id').DataTable();
});

$('#table_id').DataTable({
  paging: false,
  searching: false,
  select: true
});

$("input[type='text']").change(function() {
  var regs = $(this).val().toUpperCase();

  if ($(this).hasClass("reg")) {
    var cars_name = $(regss)
      .filter(function(i, n) {
        return n.name === regs;
      });
    if (cars_name.length > 0) {
      $(this).closest("tr").find(".name").text(cars_name[0].values)
      $(this).closest('td').find("span").show().text($(this).val());
      $(this).hide();

    } else {
      $(this).closest("tr").find(".name").text("Not a valid Registration")

    }

  }
});

$("input[type='time']").change(function() {
  $(this).closest('td').find("span").show().text($(this).val());
  $(this).hide();



});


$(".reset").click(function() {
  $(".answer").html("");
  $("input").show();
});

$(".confirm").click(function() {

  $("#table_id tbody tr").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find(".reg").val() == "") {
      $(this).find(".name").text("Please enter valid Registration")
    }
    var cmra = $(this).find(".cmr").val()
    var mtnc = $(this).find(".mtnc").val()
    if ((cmra != null && cmra != "") && (mtnc != null && mtnc != "")) {
      var miles = Math.ceil((parseInt(mtnc - cmra)) / 44);
      $(this).find(".charge").text(miles)
    } else if (cmra == null || cmra == "") {
      $(this).find(".charge").text("Please enter the current miles left")
    } else if (mtnc == null || mtnc == "") {
      $(this).find(".charge").text("Please enter the mtnc  left")
    }
  })
});
$(".generate").click(function() {
  var count = 0;//for second table
  //remove any bg color in td
  $("#table_id_2 tbody td").css({
    "background-color": ""
  });
  //loop through first table to get datas
  $("#table_id tbody tr").each(function() {
//get required datas
    var car1_name = $(this).find(".name").text();
    var mtnc = $(this).find(".mtnc").val();
    var charges = $(this).find(".charge").text();
    var times = $(this).find('.time').val();
 //get hours i.e : 11:30 so take "11"
    var hrs = times.split(":")[0];
   //get leaves
    var leaves = parseInt(hrs - charges);
    //loop through second table starting from tr eq 0
     $("#table_id_2 tbody tr:eq(" + count + ")").each(function() {
      $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text(car1_name);//set car_name
//if hrs = 11 and leaves = 2 so loop from 11 -10-9-8..
      for (var i = hrs; i >= leaves; i--) {
      //add bg to that td
        $(this).find("td[value=" + i + "]").css({
          "background-color": "yellow"
        });;
      }
      // add exit miles 
      $(this).find(".exit").text(mtnc)
    });
    count++;//increment to go to next tr 

  })


});
$(".reset").click(function() {
  $(".answer").html("");
  $("input").show();
});
```

```css
.table {
  border: 3px solid #000032;
  width: 100%;
}
button {
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    font: inherit;
    color: white;
    background-color: #000032;
    margin: 5px;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<div id="table-section" class="table-section">

  <div>
    <button class="confirm">Confirm</button>
    <button class="reset" type="reset">Reset Reg</button>
    <table id="table_id" class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th id="th-reg">Registration</th>
          <th id="th-name">Name</th>
          <th id="th-cmr">Current Miles Range</th>
          <th id="th-cni">Miles needed for next trip</th>
          <th id="th-tl">Hours to charge for next trip</th>
          <th id="tpoc">Time Leaving</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="answer"></span><input class="reg question" id="car-1-reg" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Registration"></input>
          </td>
          <td id="car-1-name" class="name value-reset"></td>
          <td><span id="car-1-cmra" class="answer" type="number"></span><input id="car-1-cmr" class="cmr question" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Miles Left"></input>
          </td>
          <td><span id="car-1-mtnc" class="answer" type="number"></span><input id="car-1-mtnc" class="mtnc question" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Miles needed"></input>
          </td>
          <td id="car-1-charge-needed" class="charge"></td>
          <td id="car-1-tl" class="tl"><span class="answer time-input" type="text"></span><input class="time" type="time" min="07:00" max="18:00" required></input>
          </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="answer"></span><input id="car-2-reg" class="reg" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Registration"></input>
          </td>
          <td id="car-2-name" class="name"></td>
          <td><span id="car-2-cmra" class="answer" type="number"></span><input id="car-2-cmr" class="cmr" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Miles Left"></input>
          </td>
          <td><span id="car-2-mtnc" class="answer" type="number"></span><input id="car-2-mtnc" class="mtnc" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Miles needed"></input>
          </td>
          <td id="car-2-charge-needed" class="charge"></td>
          <td id="car-2-tl" class="tl"><span class="answer" type="time"></span><input class="time" type="time" min="07:00" max="18:00" required></input>
          </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="answer"></span><input id="car-3-reg" class="reg" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Registration"></input>
          </td>
          <td id="car-3-name" class="name"></td>
          <td><span id="car-3-cmra" class="answer"></span><input id="car-3-cmr" class="cmr" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Miles Left"></input>
          </td>
          <td><span id="car-3-mtnc" class="answer" type="number"></span><input id="car-3-mtnc" class="mtnc" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Miles needed"></input>
          </td>
          <td id="car-3-charge-needed" class="charge"></td>
          <td id="car-3-tl" class="tl"><span class="answer" type="time"></span><input class="time" type="time" min="07:00" max="18:00" required></input>
          </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="answer"></span><input id="car-4-reg" class="reg" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Registration"></input>
          </td>
          <td id="car-4-name" class="name"></td>
          <td><span id="car-4-cmra" class="answer"></span><input id="car-4-cmr" class="cmr" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Miles Left"></input>
          </td>
          <td><span id="car-4-mtnc" class="answer" type="number"></span><input id="car-4-mtnc" class="mtnc" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Miles needed"></input>
          </td>
          <td id="car-4-charge-needed" class="charge"></td>
          <td id="car-4-tl" class="tl"><span class="answer" type="time"></span><input class="time" type="time" min="07:00" max="18:00" required></input>
          </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="answer"></span><input id="car-5-reg" class="reg" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Registration"></input>
          </td>
          <td id="car-5-name" class="name"></td>
          <td><span id="car-5-cmra" class="answer"></span><input id="car-5-cmr" class="cmr" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Miles Left"></input>
          </td>
          <td><span id="car-5-mtnc" class="answer" type="number"></span><input id="car-5-mtnc" class="mtnc" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Miles needed"></input>
          </td>
          <td id="car-5-charge-needed" class="charge"></td>
          <td id="car-5-tl" class="tl"><span class="answer" type="time"></span><input class="time" type="time" min="07:00" max="18:00" required></input>
          </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="answer"></span><input id="car-6-reg" class="reg" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Registration"></input>
          </td>
          <td id="car-6-name" class="name"></td>
          <td><span id="car-6-cmra" class="answer"></span><input id="car-6-cmr" class="cmr" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Miles Left"></input>
          </td>
          <td><span id="car-6-mtnc" class="answer" type="number"></span><input id="car-6-mtnc" class="mtnc" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Miles needed"></input>
          </td>
          <td id="car-6-charge-needed" class="charge"></td>
          <td id="car-6-tl" class="tl"><span class="answer" type="time"></span><input class="time" type="time" min="07:00" max="18:00" required></input>
          </td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
    <button id="generate-time-table" class="generate">Generate Schedule</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="schedule " class="schedule">
  <table id="table_id_2" class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th id="car">Car</th>
        <th id="7" value="7">7 - 8</th>
        <th id="8" value="8">8 - 9</th>
        <th id="9" value="9">9 - 10</th>
        <th id="10" value="10">10 - 11</th>
        <th id="11" value="11">11- 12</th>
        <th id="12" value="12">12 -13</th>
        <th id="13" value="13">13 - 14</th>
        <th id="14" value="14">14 - 15</th>
        <th id="15" value="15">15 - 16</th>
        <th id="16" value="16">16 - 17</th>
        <th id="exit_miles" class="exit">Exit Miles</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
  <!-- add attrr value to each td -->
      <tr id="tr-car-1">
        <td id="car-2">Car 1</td>
        <td id="7" value="7"></td>
        <td id="8" value="8"></td>
        <td id="9" value="9"></td>
        <td id="10" value="10"></td>
        <td id="11" value="11"></td>
        <td id="12" value="12"></td>
        <td id="13" value="13"></td>
        <td id="14" value="14"></td>
        <td id="15" value="15"></td>
        <td id="16" value="16"></td>
        <td id="car-1-exit-miles" class="exit">60</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="car-2">Car 2</td>
        <td id="7" value="7"></td>
        <td id="8" value="8"></td>
        <td id="9" value="9"></td>
        <td id="10" value="10"></td>
        <td id="11" value="11"></td>
        <td id="12" value="12"></td>
        <td id="13" value="13"></td>
        <td id="14" value="14"></td>
        <td id="15" value="15"></td>
        <td id="16" value="16"></td>
        <td id="car-2-exit-miles" class="exit">60</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="car-3">Car 3</td>
        <td id="7" value="7"></td>
        <td id="8" value="8"></td>
        <td id="9" value="9"></td>
        <td id="10" value="10"></td>
        <td id="11" value="11"></td>
        <td id="12" value="12"></td>
        <td id="13" value="13"></td>
        <td id="14" value="14"></td>
        <td id="15" value="15"></td>
        <td id="16" value="16"></td>
        <td id="car-3-exit-miles" class="exit">60</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="car-4">Car 4</td>
        <td id="7" value="7"></td>
        <td id="8" value="8"></td>
        <td id="9" value="9"></td>
        <td id="10" value="10"></td>
        <td id="11" value="11"></td>
        <td id="12" value="12"></td>
        <td id="13" value="13"></td>
        <td id="14" value="14"></td>
        <td id="15" value="15"></td>
        <td id="16" value="16"></td>
        <td id="car-4-exit-miles" class="exit">60</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="car-5">Car 5</td>
        <td id="7" value="7"></td>
        <td id="8" value="8"></td>
        <td id="9" value="9"></td>
        <td id="10" value="10"></td>
        <td id="11" value="11"></td>
        <td id="12" value="12"></td>
        <td id="13" value="13"></td>
        <td id="14" value="14"></td>
        <td id="15" value="15"></td>
        <td id="16" value="16"></td>
        <td id="car-5-exit-miles" class="exit">60</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="car-6">Car 6</td>
        <td id="7" value="7"></td>
        <td id="8" value="8"></td>
        <td id="9" value="9"></td>
        <td id="10" value="10"></td>
        <td id="11" value="11"></td>
        <td id="12" value="12"></td>
        <td id="13" value="13"></td>
        <td id="14" value="14"></td>
        <td id="15" value="15"></td>
        <td id="16" value="16"></td>
        <td id="car-6-exit-miles" class="exit">60</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>
</div>
```

***Note*** : Your time input is not validating `min` and `max` you need to validate it using jquery so that user do not input beyond that time.

Comment: Wow, thank you Swati, that is brilliant. Thank you for explaining it to me. I am going through what you said and will implement it in to my code. 
I do have one problem when trying to implement it, i keep getting "Cannot Read Property 'split' of Undefined". I am looking how to solve the problem. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I managed to fix the split error, I needed to change the span class from time-input , to time, instead of the input. When you click generate, the details appear, but the background doesn't change colour. Am investigating further.

Comment: I am such a wally, I didn't update the HTML, once I did this it all worked perfectly. Thank you so much, this is amazing, thank you!

Comment: I am such a wally, I didn't update the HTML, once I did this it all worked perfectly. Thank you so much, this is amazing, thank you!

Comment: One last question, sorry. I need to have the leave time, not coloured out. I.e if the car leaves at 16.00 the table cell 16-17 shouldn't be blocked out. Do I change this code:       $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text(car1_name);//set car_name
//if hrs = 11 and leaves = 2 so loop from 11 -10-9-8..
      for (var i = hrs; i >= leaves; i--) {
      //add bg to that td
        $(this).find("td[value=" + i + "]").css({
          "background-color": "yellow"
        });  to achieve that?

Comment: Instead of `>=` just put `>` inside for loop condition because I thought you need last time as well so I have put `=` as well.. removing that should work.

Comment: Thank you, i really appreciate you taking the time out to help me with this. Hopefully one day I can return the favour :) I worded it badly, sorry. Thank you again.